# Use regular expressions to remove quotation marks in R data frame

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Here's what my data set (named g) looks like now. I'm working in R.

```
Q.35 | Q.36 | age | gender | country 

2 | 2 | 1 | 20 | 2 | AU"       
3 | 5 | 5 | 21 | 1 | AU"
```

I want to remove those quotation marks on the country codes (AU instead of AU"). But the regexs I've tried haven't worked.

```
h <- grep("\"", "", g)

h <- grep(""", "", g)

h <- grep('"', '', g)
```

How can I delete those quotation marks?

### Edit

It worked! I should have been using gsub, not grep.

But gsub messed up my code, so I realized that I had to apply gsub to a specific variable, like this:

```
h$country.f <- gsub("\"", "", h$country.f)
```

Comment: `sub`/`gsub` not `grep`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep` only searches for matches within each element of a character vector, if you want to replace the first occurrence of a specific pattern, use `sub` or `gsub` to replace all the occurrences.

**Example**:

```
> h <- data.frame(age = c(20,21), country = c('AU"', 'AU"'))
> h$country <- gsub('"', '', h$country)
> h

#   age country
# 1  20      AU
# 2  21      AU
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, there is also nice package `stringr` that provides a convenient way of manipulating strings:

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(20,21), country = c('AU"', 'AU"'))
require(stringr)
df$country <- str_replace_all(string = df$country, pattern = '"', replacement = "")
```

I like using it as it's got very straightforward syntax.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think of that! Thanks!